# Gettext wrong default language

Tags: c++, translation, gettext

I'm using gettext to handle translations on a C++ project of mine. I generate the .pot file using xgettext and then I create .po files for spanish and english using msginit (en.po and es.po) .

The problem is that, although the locale on my system is set to spanish, the `.po` file that gets automatically filled is `en.po`, where it should be `es.po`, because all strings are by default written in spanish in my project. All in all, the content from `en.po` should be the one in `es.po` and viceversa.

Is there a way of letting `xgettext` and/or `msginit` that spanish is the default language?

Comment: this is bad practice to use non-english language as default.

Comment: Bad practice? I don't think so. If a project is first developed for an isolated, non-english-speaking community, and later it's thought to be suitable for the general public, then why english would be the default?

Comment: Nope, I gave up. I'm afraid it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using other languages than English as the base language of your project has been considered a recipe for trouble for a long time. This is no longer true today.

With msginit 0.19.8.1, when you run `msginit -l en -i project.pot`, the file `en.po` gets created but all translations are initialized with their original value. Obviously `msginit` assumes that English is the base language of the project. But that can be easily fixed: Just open the `en.po` in your editor and throw away all entries but the first one (the PO header).

When invoking `xgettext` you should always give it the option `--from-code=utf-8`.  Other than that there are no problems to use another base language than English.